# Decoding php code

Tags: base64, decode, encode

I have recently installed a word press theme on my site. And i am trying to remove the credit links from the footer and sidebar, the code was in encrypted format. The theme is not functioning properly if i try to remove the links, I tried decoding using base 64 converters, but it does not helped me.

Can anyone expert let me know what kind of encoding is this and tell me how can i decode it.

Thanks in advance.

Here i am have pasted the code
http://pastebin.com/ZLGRN9ey

Answer (score 0):

It's encoded in base64 if you look at the end of the file.

`@eval(base64_decode($m));unset($m);`

`@eval` executes the PHP. It looks like it is first decoded with the base64_decode function, though. Then, variable `m` is removed. If you want to see it decoded, do `echo base64_decode($m)`. Even if you do this, though, it's likely that the code would still be rather obfuscated and unreadable. Try emailing the developer for the source.

Comment: Hi mjkaufer,

Thanks for the reply..But i took this as challenge, is there anyway i can get the source code? There should be another way to decode this code. I am sure coders from stackoverflow can decode this.

Comment: ok, finally i got it using this

echo (v_8Mx05neqMdy($v_7dTvwXWxo1U,$v_d0ZZhfbraAQ));